# Excel error identifying in reverse

Tags: excel-2010

Is there a way to get Excel to identify if a cell contains any words other than the keywords?

Then, if they are there show an error rather than saying that the keywords are there?

Comment: I don't know what this means...

Comment: The post was edited for a better explanation of the question.

Comment: How many keywords are you talking about? Are they in a specific order? Are they separated by commas or anything else? It'd help me to see an example of the results vs the keywords.

Comment: There are 18 keywords that right now I have set it up so that when any of them appear in this one cell it will respond with the word error. Commas or order does not matter, just that they are there. However, I would like all of these words to be recognized as blank, and anything outwith that as the error.

Comment: Or to say...Error, then the word that is not a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If your keywords are represented by A to R, maybe:

```
=IF(LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"R",""),"A",""),"B",""),"C",""),"D",""),"E",""),"F",""),"G",""),"H",""),"I",""),"J",""),"K",""),"L",""),"M",""),"N",""),"O",""),"P",""),"Q","")))=0,"","Error")
```